# Has the Weibull distribution got pseudovariance?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance, weibull-distribution, dispersion

I have a scholar question about the Weibull distribution, which can be parameterised, among other options, like follow:

$f(t)= \lambda \alpha t^{\alpha-1}{exp} \left \{  \lambda t^\alpha \right \}$

I understand that the Weibull is in general not part of the Exponential family. However, I also have read that if we take the shape parameter $\alpha$ to be a nuisance parameter then it can be considered to be a a generalised model with link function: inverse.

My problem is that I would like to obtain the pseudo-variance $\widetilde{\sigma}$  which is an approximation to the normal model variance for non-normal models, and is calculated using the likelihood of the model by:

$\widetilde{\sigma} = \frac{-1}{{L}''}=\phi\left [ \frac{1}{V} {\frac{\partial }{\partial \mu}}^{2} \right ]$

The equation above holds assuming $y = \mu$.
Note that for a generalized linear model it can be calculated with $\mu$, $df/d\mu$ and the dispersion parameter $\phi$.

Do you think that using the MLE estimates or MAP estimates for $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ one can get the pseudovariance for the Weibull model?

Thanks a lot, I am really struggling with this question.

Comment: Please find here more information about the pseudovariance calculation in page 15 : https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ejs/1513306866

Comment: Please don't make us click through to a long paper and read it in order to understand your question!  Instead, just summarize what the pseudovariance is in the text of your question.

Comment: I am sorry jbowman, I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi all, actually I found that the question is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902568/mean-and-variance-of-the-weibull-distribution Because my question was to find the pseudovariance of Weibull thinking of it as a GLM , when is not. And here they have prrof instead the variance of the Weibull which is more exact than the pseudovariance...